# Proof of the identity $2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} \binom{n+k}{k}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I just found this identity but without any proof, could you just give me an hint how I could prove it?
$$2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} \cdot \binom{n+k}{k}$$

I know that $$2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$$ but that didn't help me

Comment: Try induction. Note that $\binom{2n}n = 2\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prove it by induction on $n$. Here’s a start. Let

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+k}k\;;$$

clearly $f(0)=1=2^0$. Assume that $f(n)=2^n$ for some $n\ge 0$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
f(n+1)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}2^{-k}\binom{n+1+k}k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}2^{-k}\left(\binom{n+k}k+\binom{n+k}{k-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}2^{-k}\binom{n+k}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2^{-k}\binom{n+k}{k-1}\\
&=2^{-(n+1)}\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+k}k+\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-(k+1)}\binom{n+1+k}k\\
&=2^{-(n+1)}\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+2^n+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+1+k}k\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$f(n+1)=2^{-(n+1)}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+1+k}k\;.$$

Now combine these results and use the fact that

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+\binom{2n+1}n=2\binom{2n+1}n$$

to complete the induction step.

Answer (score 15):

Let's do this in lazy, stream of consciousness fashion, adjusting little details one by one until it looks like a recognizable enumeration.

First combinatorialize it by multiplying the whole thing by $2^n$, to

$$2^{2n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{n-k} \cdot \binom{n+k}{k}$$

This looks better, because $(n-k)$ and $(n+k)$ look like a decomposition of $2n$.  The left side counts all subsets of a $2n$ element set, so maybe something about the larger and the smaller subset in the partition of $2n$ elements into a subset and its complement.  Some fuzzy feeling about needing to break the symmetry when the sets are of equal size tells to multiply by $2$ and consider subsets of a $2n+1$ element set, which as a partition of the set has a larger and a smaller part.  So,

$$2^{2n+1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2 \times 2^{n-k} \cdot \binom{n+k}{k}$$  or

$$2^{2n+1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2 \times 2^{n-k} \cdot \binom{n+k}{n}$$

Better!  A subset of a size $2n+1$ set is equivalent to a partition into (larger set with more than $n$ elements) $\cup$ (smaller set with less than $n$ elements), and a choice (the $\times 2$) of which one is the subset.  And we can pick the larger subset by first selecting its largest $n+1$ elements, then adding some random subset from the lower indexed elements (this is the $2^{n-k}$), and... ok, it is all clear now:

> From the first $2n+1$ integers, select a subset by partitioning into a large and a small subset and picking ($\times 2$) one of them as the set.  Determine the large subset, which has at least $n+1$ elements, by selecting an index $j$ from $1$ to $n+1$ as the location of the $(n+1)$th-largest element of the set, selecting the $n$ elements above $j$ (there are ${2n+1 - j} \choose {n}$ options) and adding any subset of the elements below $j$ (there are $2^{j-1}$ of those).  This is the last sum with $k = n+1 - j$.

In the opposite direction, divide by $2^n$ to get

$$1 = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-(n+k)} \cdot \binom{n+k}{n}$$

and look for a natural probability process that delivers this distribution. One answer:

> Throw a coin to determine whether voters $1, 2, \ldots$ are supporting candidate $A$ or $B$ in an election, and stop the process when one candidate reaches $n+1$ votes.  Stopping happens at a time $t$ between $n+1$ and $2n+1$ steps, and if $k=t-1-n$, the set of times at which the victorious candidate received votes before time $t$ is one of ${{t-1} \choose n} = {{n+k} \choose n}$ possibilities.

I think this process is essentially the same as what is sometimes called Banach's Matchbox Problem.

Comment: Your "opposite direction" is a bit terse. Do I understand correctly that $\frac12 = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-(n+k-1)} \binom{n+k}n$ gives the total probability that $A$ will win, as sum over the probabilities that she will win after $n+k+1$ votes, for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: I think he means to say that the process has a probability 1 of stopping, and each summand is the probability the process stops at that specific time.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to generalize, but equation $(2)$ shows why $x=\frac12$ is needed to make a simple equation.

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x^k\binom{n+k+1}{k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x^k\left[\binom{n+k}{k}+\binom{n+k}{k-1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^nx^k\binom{n+k}{k}+x^{n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\\
&+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x^{k+1}\binom{n+k+1}{k}-x^{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Moving terms around and multiplying by $(1-x)^n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1cm}(1-x)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x^k\binom{n+k+1}{k}
&=(1-x)^n\sum_{k=0}^nx^k\binom{n+k}{k}\\
&+(1-x)^n\left[x^{n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n}-x^{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\right]\\
&=(1-x)^n\sum_{k=0}^nx^k\binom{n+k}{k}\\
&+(1-x)^n\left[\frac12x^{n+1}-x^{n+2}\right]\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
since $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}{n}$ and $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+\binom{2n+1}{n}=\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$.

Setting $x=\frac12$ in $(2)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
2^{-n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}2^{-k}\binom{n+k+1}{k}
&=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+k}{k}\\
&\vdots\\
&=2^{-0}\sum_{k=0}^02^{-k}\binom{0+k}{k}\\[9pt]
&=1\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+k}{k}=2^n\tag{4}
$$

Comment: That looks like a very neat proof. For equation (3) how did you conclude that it equals 1?

Comment: @hypergeometric: note that the first line in $(3)$ says that the sum for $n$ equals the sum for $n+1$. Setting $n=0$ gives the sum to be $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Very clever, this "built-in induction" $f(n+1)=f(n)$.

Comment: I've added a line for $n=0$. Hopefully, that makes things a bit clearer. If not, perhaps I should add some desription around $(3)$.

Comment: Yes, that certainly helps. I suppose those who cannot understand should ask, or read the comments first.

Comment: If you don't substitute $x=\frac 12$, would you be able to prove Gosper's identity $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n+k\choose k}[x^{n+1}(1-x)^k+x^k(1-x)^{n+1}]=1$$? See equation $69$ here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html. If this can be done, then putting $x=\frac 12$ gives the result directly.

Comment: @hypergeometric Inspired by robjohn's answer I proved the general formula.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} {n+k\choose k} = 2^n.$$

We introduce the Iverson bracket

$$[[k\le n]] =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n-k+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\; dz$$

so we may extend $k$ to infinity, getting

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{k\ge 0} 2^{-k} {n+k\choose n} z^k
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-z/2)^{n+1}}
\; dz.$$

We evaluate this using the negative  of the residues at $z=1, z=2$ and
$z=\infty.$ Here the contour does not include the other two finite poles
which also ensures that the geometric series converges. We could choose
$\epsilon = 1/2.$ We get for the residue at $z=1$

$$- \frac{1}{(1/2)^{n+1}} = - 2^{n+1}.$$

For the residue at $z=2$ we write

$$(-1)^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=2}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(z/2-1)^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{n+1} 2^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=2}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{n} 2^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=2}
\frac{1}{(2+(z-2))^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1+(z-2)}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{n} \mathrm{Res}_{z=2}
\frac{1}{(1+(z-2)/2)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1+(z-2)}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}.$$

This is

$$(-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {n+q\choose q} 2^{-q} (-1)^{n-q}
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n+q\choose q} 2^{-q} = S_n.$$

Finally do the residue at $z=\infty$ getting (this also follows by
inspection having degree zero in the numerator and degree $2n+3$ in the
denominator)

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-z/2)^{n+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^{n+1} \frac{1}{1-1/z} \frac{1}{(1-1/2/z)^{n+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z}
z^{n+1} \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{z^{n+1}}{(z-1/2)^{n+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} z^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{(z-1/2)^{n+1}} = 0.$$

Using the fact that the residues sum to zero we thus obtain

$$S_n - 2^{n+1} + S_n = 0$$

which yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S_n = 2^n.}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{2^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^{-k}{n + k \choose k}:\ {\large ?}}$

> $\ds{\tt\mbox{The following method is a straightforward one}}$.

Hereafter we'll use the identity
$$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\ds{\quad{\,m \choose \ell\,}=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ b\ >\ 0}
{\pars{1 + z}^{m} \over z^{\ell + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^{-k}{n + k \choose k}}
> =\sum_{k = -\infty}^{n}2^{-k}{n + k \choose n}
> =\sum_{k = \infty}^{-n}2^{k}{n - k \choose n}
> =\sum_{k = \infty}^{0}2^{k - n}{2n - k \choose n}
> \\[5mm]&=2^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}2^{k}{2n - k \choose n}
> =2^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}2^{k}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{2n - k} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=2^{-n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{2 \over 1 + z}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=2^{-n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> {1 \over 1 - 2/\pars{1 + z}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =2^{-n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{2n + 1} \over z^{n + 1}\pars{z - 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=2^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n + 1} \over z^{n + 2 + k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =2^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{2n + 1 \choose n + k + 1}
> \end{align}

$$
\mbox{Then,}\quad\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^{-k}{n + k \choose k}}
=2^{-n}\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n + 1 \choose n - k}}\tag{1}
$$

> The $\ds{\color{#c00000}{\mbox{"red expression"}}}$ in $\pars{1}$
>   becomes:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n + 1 \choose n - k}}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{-n}{2n + 1 \choose n + k}
> =\sum_{k = n}^{0}{2n + 1 \choose k}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1}{2n + 1 \choose k}
> -\sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n + 1}{2n + 1 \choose k}
> \\[3mm]&=2^{2n + 1} -\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n + 1 \choose k + n + 1}
> =2^{2n + 1} - \color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n + 1 \choose n - k}}\ \imp\
> \begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
> \quad\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n + 1 \choose n - k}} = 2^{2n}\quad
> \\ \\ \hline
> \end{array}
> \end{align}

We replace this result in expression $\pars{1}$:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^{-k}{n + k \choose k} = 2^{n}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by robjohn's answer I show a more general statement: for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #0000A0]{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}((1-x)^{n+1}x^k+x^{n+1}(1-x)^k)=1}$$
Such identity appears as equation 69 at this [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html) (see hypergeometric's comment).  OP's identity follows by setting $x=1/2$.

Let 
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}x^k$$
then we have to show by induction that
$$(1-x)^{n+1}f_n(x)+x^{n+1}f_n(x)=1.$$
Base case: for $n=0$  it is trivial.

\noindent Inductive step step. We note that
\begin{align*}
f_{n+1}(x)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n+k}{k}+\binom{n+1+k-1}{k-1}\right)x^k\\
&=f_n(x)+\binom{2n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1}+xf_{n+1}(x)-\binom{2n+2}{n+1}x^{n+2}\\
&=f_n(x)+\binom{2n+1}{n}x^{n+1}+xf_{n+1}(x)-2\binom{2n+1}{n}x^{n+2}
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$(1-x)f_{n+1}(x)=f_n(x)+\binom{2n+1}{n}x^{n+1}(1-2x)$$
Hence
$$(1-x)^{n+2}f_{n+1}(x)
=(1-x)^{n+1}f_n(x)+\binom{2n+1}{n}(1-x)^{n+1}x^{n+1}(1-2x)$$
and, by replacing $x$ with $(1-x)$, we get
$$x^{n+2}f_{n+1}(1-x)
=x^{n+1}f_n(1-x)-\binom{2n+1}{n}x^{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1}(1-2x).$$
Finally, by adding the last two equations we find
$$(1-x)^{n+2}f_{n+1}(x)+x^{n+2}f_{n+1}(1-x)=
x^{n+1}f_n(1-x)+(1-x)^{n+1}f_n(x)=1$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+m}{m}z^k=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}-\frac{z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^{m+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n+k}{k}(1-z)^k$$
$$n=m, z=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+n}{n}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}-\frac{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}$$
$$S=2^{n+1}-S, 2S = 2^{n+1}, S=2^n$$

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon the *Lagrange inversion formula*. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^n]\frac{1}{1-2z}=[z^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^jz^j=2^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+k}{k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{-n-1}{k}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{z}{2}\right)^{n+1}(1-z)}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^n]\left.\left(\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{w}{2}\right)(1-w)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{2}}}\right)\right|_{w=\frac{z}{1-\frac{w}{2}}}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^n]\left.\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}\right|_{w=1-\sqrt{1-2z}}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-2z}\\
> &\color{blue}{=2^n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we observe the sum is the coefficient of the convolution of two series
  \begin{align*}
  [z^n]\left(\sum_{k}a_kz^k\right)\left(\sum_{l}b_lz^l\right)=[z^n]\sum_{N}\left(\sum_{k=0}^Na_k b_{N-k}\right)z^N
  =\sum_{k=0}^na_k b_{n-k}
  \end{align*}
  Here with $a_k=\binom{-n-1}{k}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$ and $b_k=1$.
- In (3) we use the *Lagrange Inversion Formula* in the form G6 stated in R. Sprugnolis (etal) paper [Lagrange Inversion: when and how](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/226195157_Lagrange_Inversion_When_and_How/file/e0b495230d098ec3f7.pdf).

\begin{align*}
[z^n]F(z)\Phi(z)^n=[z^n]\left.\frac{F(w)}{1-z\Phi'(w)}\right|_{w=z\Phi(w)}
\end{align*}

Here with $\Phi(z)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}$ and $F(z)=\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{z}{2}\right)(1-z)}$. It follows since $w=z\Phi(w)$:
\begin{align*}
z\Phi^{\prime}(w)=\frac{z}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{w}{2}\right)^2}
=\frac{z}{2}\Phi^2(w)=\frac{w}{2}\Phi(w)=\frac{w}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{2}}
\end{align*}

- In (4) we simplify the expression and we select the solution $w=w(z)$ from $w=\frac{z}{1-\frac{w}{2}}$ which can be expanded in a power series.