# Combinatorics identity sum of

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Prove that:

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{k}{2n-k}2^k = 2^{2n}$$

By using only combinatorics identities.

Comment: There is something wrong with the question. $\dbinom{k}{2n-k} = 0$ for $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: I think you should write (2n-k) over k instead.

Comment: I think that the binomial coefficient should be $\dbinom{2n-k}n$. That at least gives a correct result.

Answer (score 4):

From [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389099/proof-of-the-identity-2n-sum-limits-k-0n-2-k-binomnkk) we have

$$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\binom{n+k}k=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n2^{n-k}\binom{n+k}k=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{2n-k}{n-k}=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{2n-k}n\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom{2n-k}n=2^{2n}\;,$$

which I suspect is the intended result.