# How to prove this identity in a combinatorial way?

Tags: combinatorics

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}{2 n+1} \\ {k}\end{array}\right)=2^{2 n}
\end{equation}
I managed to prove it in an algebric way but not in combinatorial one.

Thanks!

Not a duplicate.

Comment: Hint: The left hand side counts subsets of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2n+1\right\}$ that contain less than half the $2n+1$ elements. The right hand side counts subsets that don't contain $2n+1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combinatorics identity sum of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389690/combinatorics-identity-sum-of)

Comment: @JeanMarie: nope.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" was not for your comment but for the OP.

Comment: @JeanMarie: But the OP is not a duplicate of that thread.

Comment: The right hand side is half the number of all subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{1,2,\dots,2n+1\}$.

We wish to prove that $\mathcal{A}=\{A\subseteq S:~|A|\leq n\}$ is in bijection with $\mathcal{B}=\{B\subseteq S:~2n+1\notin B\}$.  It is clear that $|\mathcal{A}|$ is counted by the LHS of your identity while $|\mathcal{B}|$ is counted by the RHS of your identity.

Consider the function $f:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ given by:

$$f(A) = \begin{cases} A&\text{if }2n+1\notin A\\ S\setminus A&\text{if }2n+1\in A\end{cases}$$

Notice that if $2n+1\notin A$ then $|f(A)|=|A|\leq n$.  On the other hand, if $2n+1\in A$ then $|f(A)|=|S\setminus A| = 2n+1-|A|\geq n+1$

Suppose then that $f(A_1) = f(A_2)$.  This implies that either $2n+1$ is in both $A_1$ and $A_2$ or it is in neither.  In the first case, that would imply that $A_1=A_2$.  Otherwise, that would imply that $S\setminus A_1=S\setminus A_2$ which in turn implies that $A_1=A_2$.  Therefore, the function is injective.

For surjectivity, consider an arbitrary subset $B$ not containing $2n+1$ of $S$.  In the event that $|B|\leq n$ then $B\in\mathcal{A}$ and $f(B)=B$.  Otherwise, if $|B|\geq n+1$ we have $S\setminus B\in \mathcal{A}$ and that $f(S\setminus B)=B$.

Thus the function is a bijection and the identity is proven.