# Help with a Binomial Identity: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k}2^{-k} = 2^{n+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, binomial-coefficients

The following is a problem from the 5th edition of Niven's *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*:

Problem 23 of Section 1.4 asks us to prove that

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k}2^{-k} = 2^{n+1}.$$

I believe I proved it using generating functions, but I would love to have my proof verified and if possible, could someone provide a hint to an alternative proof of the fact. Generating functions have not been covered in this section yet, so I would prefer to figure out how to prove this identity with slightly less powerful tools (if that makes sense).

**PROOF** The right hand side is the coefficient $[x^n]$ of the generating function $$\frac{2}{1-2x}.$$

On the left hand side, we have that the corresponding generating function of the sequence is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+n}{n}\frac{1}{2^k}x^n &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\\
&= \frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2-2x)^k}\\
&= \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2-2x}}\\
&=\frac{2}{1-2x} = RHS
\end{align*}

Comment: You can also solve problem 7 in that section and get this one as corollary.

Comment: I did use problem 7 (at least "formally") when working with the generating function of $\left\{\binom{n+k}{n}\right\}_{n}$.

Oh, I think I see what you mean. Evaluating $z=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha=n$. Very clever, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative proof is to use a simple induction on $n$. You have

$$x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+1+k}{k}2^{-k}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{n+1+k}{k}2^{-k}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k}2^{-k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k+1}{k}2^{-k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k}{k}2^{-k}+\frac{x}{2}$$

so that applying the IH and solving leads to

$x=2\cdot 2^{n+1}=2^{n+2}$.

Comment: I like this answer. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n+k \choose  k}2^{-k} = 2^{n+1}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n+k \choose  k}2^{-k}}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}{-n - 1 \choose  k}2^{-k}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-n - 1 \choose  k}\pars{-\,\half}^{k}
> \\[3mm]&=\bracks{1 + \pars{-\,\half}}^{-n - 1}=\pars{\half}^{-n - 1}
> =\color{#66f}{\Large 2^{n + 1}}
> \end{align}

Comment: Nice answer. Very clever use of Upper Negation. Would you be able to use this method (or a variant of it) if the summation is taken only to $n$ instead of $\infty$? The result is $2^n$ instead of $2^{n+1}$. Thought that problem has been posted on MSE before but could not locate it.

Comment: @hypergeometric I'll check your new question tomorrow because it's too late over here. Thanks.

Comment: @hypergeometric I remembered [I already solved over here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/905568/85343). The above 'trick' doesn't work in that case because we need to keep the $k$ variable unchanged in ${\cdots \choose k}$ in order to rebuild the Newton binomial. You can write
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n + k \choose k}2^{-k}
=
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n + k \choose k}2^{-k}
-2^{-n - 1}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{2n + k + 1 \choose k + n + 1}2^{-k}
$$
You can see that the lower index in the second term combinatoric is not $k$ anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @Felix_Marin. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same proof provided by @mathse above, expanded for more detail.

Let
$$
F(n,k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}{k}2^{-k}=2^{n+1}
$$
Assume result is true for $n=m$, i.e.
$$
F(m,k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+k}{k}2^{-k}=2^{m+1}
$$
For $n=m+1$,
\begin{align}
F(m+1,k)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+1+k}{k}2^{-k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{m+1+k}{k}2^{-k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\binom{m+k}{k}+\binom{m+k}{k-1}\right]2^{-k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{m+k}{k}2^{-k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+k+1}{k}2^{-(k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+k}{k}2^{-k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+k+1}{k}2^{-k}\\
&=F(m,k)+\frac{1}{2}F(m+1,k)\\
&=2^{m+1}+\frac{1}{2}F(m+1,k)\\
\frac{1}{2}F(m+1,k)&=2^{m+1}\\
F(m+1,k)&=2\cdot 2^{m+1}=2^{m+2}=2^{\overline{m+1}+1}
\end{align}
i.e. also true for $n=m+1$.

For $n=0$,
$$
\text{LHS}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k}{k}2^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2=\text{RHS}
$$
i.e. true for $n=0$.

Hence, by induction, $F(n,k)=2^{n+1}$ is true for all integers $n\geq 0$.

(see the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oza8v.png))